# How do I make wordpress use the category slug instead of a query string?

Tags: wordpress

My category links are coming out like this:

```
http://localhost/sites/wordpress/?cat=1
```

How can I use the slug instead?

Also, simply navigating to the expected slug ulr gets 404:

```
http://localhost/sites/wordpress/category/category-slug
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality should work out of the box. You probably need to check your rewrite rules if your using apache. It could be caused by the fact that your wordpress is installed in a sub directory

Comment: that's what I thought to, and is what the book I'm reading has said. Also the links on the page should still show up with the slug, though, right? Even if the rewrite rules are not working?

Comment: Yes, They should still show up but you can check by going to http://localhost/sites/wordpress/wp-admin/options-permalink.php and you can select the format you need

Comment: Ok, turns out I have to "re-save" the post to get the permalink settings to work. Now the proper link shows but the url returns 404.